# Excel Macro to move data to a set location

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am using the following to insert a row of data in Excel to another Sheet based on a Selection box, all works as it should until I add more information to the Sheet, then it will add the data to the next available clear row which is always at the very bottom of the page, I need to add in a set location in the middle of my page.

I want the Start point to be a specific Cell, rather that First available Cell in column A that is empty, Is it possible to set a specific start point that will add the data and also delete it if the Selection box in de-selected?

```
Sub CheckboxClicked()
Dim cel As Range, dest As Range, rw As Range, targ As Range
Set cel = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
Set rw = Intersect(cel.EntireRow, Range("B:H")) 'This is the number of columns to be coppied over to the RAMs work sheet
'This is the destination and offset based on cell A1

With Worksheets("RAMS")
    Set dest = .Columns("A").Find(Application.Caller)
    If dest Is Nothing Then
        If cel.Value = True Then
            Set dest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            dest.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, rw.Columns.Count).Value = rw.Value
            'dest.Offset(0, rw.Columns.Count + 1).Value = Now 'Adds the date and time that the RAMS were added (Commented out)
            dest.Value = Application.Caller
        End If
    Else
        If cel.Value = False Then dest.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a specific start point" cell?

Comment: The above code will add the data to A2 if the sheet is completely empty, if there is any data in Column A it will add it to the next available row below the data, I would like to add the data from the Selection box Selections to a starting point of Column A Row 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set dest picks up the last populated cell and then goes down 1 cell (offset)

```
Set dest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

If you want a specific cell, you can replace the offset line

```
Set dest = .cells(1,1)
```

You can replace "cells(row,col)" depending on exactly where you want to paste the value.